# Why build a MEAN app on the server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, continuous-integration, gulp, mean-stack

My question is more on the lines of strategy than actual implementation.

And basically I'm wondering why do we build our MEAN apps on the server? And by build I mean getting components (npm install && bower install) and doing all the concat and minify stuff.

I'm trying to create my build system, and up until now I've been using a version of John Papa's build system, but my build is taking longer and longer on the server. So doesn't it make sense to just build everything locally and deploy it to the server? Or am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The build shouldn't happen on runtime. You have it partially right, build upfront, than deploy created artifact.

But the crucial idea is to have **Continuous Integration** in place. Meaning build server that is not on your local machine, which takes the code from SCM, builds it, run the tests, create deployable artifact and store it in some artifact repository (e.g. npm registry).

If you take it further and you also automatically deploy artifact into non-PROD envs, you are starting to dig into **Continuous Delivery** space.

If this build and deploy pipeline installs the artifact into PROD every commit, you are having **Continuous Deployment** working.

**EDIT - reaction on comment:**

The main idea is to have it **continuous**. Meaning, the **full build is kicked off on regular basis, optimally every commit/git push**.

If this is configured on you local machine and you are one man shop, that is probably fine. But as I played in my free time with various projects, I found that build on every commit may be resource intensive for my local machine and it was convenient to leave this responsibility for some third party service (especially when it's free).

There are plenty of online solutions for CI servers.
I used with success http://codeship.com and http://drone.io. http://cloudbees.com gives you hosted Jenkins. For open source projects they are free.

If you projects are not open source you will need to spend some bucks on it, but it should be cheap for one man projects.

Comment: Yes CI is a great idea but in big teams with lots of time to play around with it. I've worked in big teams with CI in place and I agree it's great to have, but currently I'm in the solopreneur space and I don't have the resources to properly deploy a CI solution and to maintain it.